# jquery date picker & unix timestamp (one hour late?)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, unix-timestamp

I have a problem, i use jquery datepicker to allow people to choose the date of birth but  i want to test it, so i select my birth date:

```
d/m/y  
17/02/1993
```

i'm saved this in database as unix timestamp, and then i convert it to normal date using php functions, but when i do so i get

```
16/02/1993
```

i check my birth date, in unix timestamp it is 729907200 but in database i have 729903600
is time zone affect it or what?

Comment: Where do you convert it in a unix timestamp? In the client or on the server? It probably is a timezone/daylight savings thing. And why convert it to a timestamp instead of using a date-field in mysql (or timestamptz in postgresql)

Comment: Yep. You should be saving it as a date object instead.

Comment: I'm using build-in time picker function to return unix timestamp, i was never convinced to this date object, many times when i ask how to save date/time in database, everyone recommend to use unix timestamp

Comment: timestamp is a unique value, that's why they probably recommened. you may use both fields if you want, but as stUrb and Blazemonger said, using date object is more practical.